# Does anyone know why this app times out when executing stored proc?

Tags: vb.net

I have been trying to execute a stored proc but each time I click to execute it from my app, it times out with following error:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Any ideas what, if anything needs to change on the routines below?

```
Private Sub Reset()
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constring").ConnectionString
    Dim storedProcName As String = "insertnewSP"
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(storedProcName, conn)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    command.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()
End Sub
Protected Sub Refresh_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Refresh.Click
    ' Clean up text to return the Gridview to it's default state
    Reset()
    strsearch.Text = ""
    SearchString = ""
    gridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried profiling the proc to see how long it takes?

Comment: Can you add the proc code? Did you try to run it directly on the server?

Comment: Unless you are specifying a timeout in the connection string, it's using the default timeout, which I believe is 30 seconds.  If it runs longer, you'll need to extend it, or refactor the stored proc.

Comment: If you execute the SP directly e.g. using SQL Management Studio, does it work fine? Can you execute pure SQL statements?

Comment: Well, first of all, does the SProc exist on the database already? If it does, how long does it need to run? The default time out might be not long enough for it to run. If you can run the SProc on the server (via query), you might want to post the code so we can see that as well.

Comment: Thanks all,

Sorry I forgot to indicate that when I run the SP on SSMS, it takes 30 seconds to run. The records populated is about 600.

Comment: @Grant, do you mean executetimeout?

If yes, I have that in web.config file:

    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" />

Comment: @Kenny, no I mean the command timeout.  Your query is likely timing out.  Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CommandTimeout is likely expiring before the call completes, try this:

```
Private Sub Reset()
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constring").ConnectionString
    Dim storedProcName As String = "insertnewSP"
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(storedProcName, conn)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    command.CommandTimeout = 180
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    command.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
    conn.Dispose()
End Sub

Protected Sub Refresh_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Refresh.Click
    ' Clean up text to return the Gridview to it's default state
    Reset()
    strsearch.Text = ""
    SearchString = ""
    gridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: @Kenny - While increasing the timeout can help, you may also with to try tuning the query so that it returns faster.  Perhaps one or more indexes are needed.